# How to set catch all email in hMailServer

Tags: hmail-server

I am using hMail Interop library from .net code to communicate with my email server. Is it possible to set catch all email server from that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Interface Domain specifies the property Postmaster. This is a string that holds the address of an account that should be used as the catch-all for the domain.

Example:

```
public void SetDomainCatchAll(String domainName, String catchAllAddress)
{
    String myUserName = "MyUserName";
    String myPassword = "MyPasword";

    // get hMailServer application instance
    Application app = new ApplicationClass();
    app.Authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);

    // check that domain and account exist
    Domain domain = app.Domains.get_ItemByName(domainName);
    Account account = domain.Accounts.get_ItemByAddress(catchAllAddress);

    // set postmaster and save changes
    domain.Postmaster = account.Address;
    domain.Save();
}
```

Of course this is very rough code with no error checking or anything, but I hope it shows you what you want to know. If you use the Administration Program afterwards you can check on the advanced tab of the domain entry that the catch-all address has been successfully set.

I tested this on hMailServer version 5.4-B1950.